# Bind dynamic JSON data to Knockout view model impossible

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout-2.0

Ok, I've been wondering what I'm doing wrong with a Knockout web app I'm trying to put together.

[Here is the code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ot9xontzxolpfeh/l5jY1DN2g_) excluding the AJAX service with my MVC PHP interface.

my.js = namespace declaration that I use for my app
data.js = contains static data which works to load the data into the view (leftPanel.php) 
appViewModel.js = call the functions that loads the data from PHP server and declare the view model.

So, basically, here is the issue:

I've an AJAX Service that works and get the data as show in accounts_JSON.txt and currencies_JSON.txt. The JSON is well formatted and in the text files, I've only added returns to make it easy to read.

In appViewModel.js, the "getCurrencies" and "getAccounts" methods are called and work properly: iterate through the JSON data and put it in the specified array.

Then, at the end of appViewModel.js, I log in the Chrome console each step because I can't find out why "my.app.data.currencies" and "my.app.data.accounts" are logged as empty when they are not (screenshot_chrome_console.png).

Those arrays are populated before the ko.applyBiddings so if I were to use "my.app.data.currencies" and "my.app.data.accounts" to populate the view, it should work but it doesn't. Only the static data "my.app.leftPanel.currencies.list" and "my.app.leftPanel.accounts.list" works.

What am I missing? I really can't see!

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've solved my issue :) Thanks to [this post](http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2012/05/09/async-data-loading-knockout-js-without-callback-hell.html) (from Irakli Nadareishvili).

My problem was definitely the loading method of the data retrieved via AJAX. Using Underscore to load the currencies and the accounts first and when, and only when all is loaded, filteredAccounts is loaded since I need the full list of accounts.

Here is the [final and cleaned-up code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj4h4i5w0nmtr84/FINAL_appViewModel.js) in case anyone is interested or stumble on the same problem.

Happy coding to all!